# MB_TASKMODAL flag for modal dialogs boxes

Tags: c++, winapi, dialog, modal-dialog, blocking

Would it be possible to create a modal dialog box with *DialogBox(Param)* that blocks all other top-level windows in its owner thread, similar message boxes created with the MB_TASKMODAL flag?

The usage scenario involves an application UI that consists of multiple top-level windows (primarily modeless dialogs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if there's an API to do this, but you can do it yourself.

Call [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to enumerate the top-level windows associated with your thread.  In your callback function call [EnableWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646291%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to disable the window (before showing the dialog) or enable it (after the dialog has closed).

Comment: EnumThreadWindows() considerably lessens the pain.  Note that losing the focus to another process is likely if re-enabling is done too late.